# request webapi with restharp

Tags: c#, post, restsharp

Goodmorning everyone,
using postan I make a request as in the figure, and I get data.
I write using the same call (at least I assume) and it returns an empty string and not a json.
Where could it be the mistake?

Thank you all

```
  var client = new RestClient("http://pp.miosito.it/API/");
            var request = new RestRequest("STHQRY", Method.POST);
            //  request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddParameter("TblName", "STSIG$");
            var response = client.Execute(request);

            var content = response.Content;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyxy3.png)

Comment: Have you checked the response code?

Answer (score 0):

Query Parameter Detail is mentioned in add Parameter. Please change the code as below

**Code:**

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://pp.miosito.it/API/");
    var request = new RestRequest("STHQRY?TblName=STSIG$", Method.POST); 

    //Request Body detail needs to be added. 
    //I assumed input is JSON. Please change the header part , if the body has different
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;
```